# How do I segregate data from each output line

Tags: python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup

I have this data from the code

```
list = [sno,state_name,active,positive,cured,death,new_active,new_positive,new_cured,new_death]
lol= [list]

def Extract(lol): 
    return [item[0] for item in lol] 
print(Extract(lol))
```

I want to create a list for every category here. One category for number, one for the name, one for 3rd set of value, and so on. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
[2, 'Andam', 635, 2985, 2309, 41, 602, 3018, 2374, 42]
[1, 'Andhr', 92208, 382469, 286720, 3541, 94209, 393090, 295248, 3633]
[3, 'Arunach', 987, 3555, 2563, 5, 1007, 3633, 2621, 5]
[4, 'Assama', 19535, 96771, 76962, 274, 19222, 98807, 79307, 278]
[5, 'Bira', 19823, 126714, 106361, 530, 19067, 128780, 109175, 538]
[6, 'Chandiga', 1539, 3376, 1796, 41, 1544, 3564, 1977, 43]
[7, 'Chargh', 10174, 24550, 14145, 231, 11136, 25988, 14607, 245]
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I have edited it with my approach. - Thank

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to Iterate over the list using enumerate():

```
lst = [2, 'Andam', 635, 2985, 2309, 41, 602, 3018, 2374, 42]

numbers= []
state_name = []
for indx, elem in enumerate(lst):
    if indx == 0:
        numbers.append(elem)
    elif indx == 1:
        state_name.append(elem)

print(numbers)
print(state_name)
```

**EDIT**:

if that is a nested list, you could change each element to `str` and then get the first element by index:

```
lst = [[2, 'Andam', 635, 2985, 2309, 41, 602, 3018, 2374, 42],
[2, 'Andam', 635, 2985, 2309, 41, 602, 3018, 2374, 42],
[1, 'Andhr', 92208, 382469, 286720, 3541, 94209, 393090, 295248, 3633],
[3, 'Arunach', 987, 3555, 2563, 5, 1007, 3633, 2621, 5],
[4, 'Assama', 19535, 96771, 76962, 274, 19222, 98807, 79307, 278],
[5, 'Bira', 19823, 126714, 106361, 530, 19067, 128780, 109175, 538],
[6, 'Chandiga', 1539, 3376, 1796, 41, 1544, 3564, 1977, 43],
[7, 'Chargh', 10174, 24550, 14145, 231, 11136, 25988, 14607, 245]]

# convert it to list of str
lst_new =[[str(x) for x in lst] for lst in lst]

numbers = [x[0] for x in lst_new]
state_names = [x[1] for x in lst_new]
# print(numbers)
print([int(x) for x in numbers])  # if you want it back in `int`
print(state_names)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
['Andam', 'Andam', 'Andhr', 'Arunach', 'Assama', 'Bira', 'Chandiga', 'Chargh']
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm unable to get the 2nd element of state list when I fo for the first state_name[0] all the names appear at once.

Comment: I get a vertical list, unlike your Horizontal one. The output you generated is what I want but I'm unable to obtain it.

Comment: @mronevsall please share a sample of your vertical list.